# Error with AWS SDK-JS API when Retrieving Seller Partner Product Catalog Inventory

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I need to retrieve the product catalog of my seller partner on Amazon. Although the API refers to this as "Inventory," I couldn't find this term in the SDK documentation. I assume that the "Catalog" namespace is the equivalent.

#### Update:

My custom application requires a list of the following product values:

ASINs
UPCs
SKUs
FNSKUs
I have read the documentation and found an API that returns what I need, which can be found here:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/fba-inventory-api-v1-use-case-guide
According to the documentation, I need to create a signature in order to use the API. However, it is noted that if I use the AWS SDK, I do not need to calculate the signature myself. Therefore, I understand that the best practice is to use the AWS SDK.

I have the necessary IAM role permissions and the SP-API app has been published. I am currently attempting to use the AWS SDK.

I have made some changes based on recommendations, but I am not completely sure what else I need to do. Here is my current code:

````
```
export const /*bundle */ start = async () => {
    const client = new MarketplaceCatalogClient({
        region: REGION,
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
        },
    });

    const params = {
        /** input parameters */
    };

    const answer = await client.send(
        new ListEntitiesCommand({ Catalog: "AWSMarketplace", EntityType: "ContainerProduct" })
    );

    console.log(100, answer);
    return answer;
};
```
````

I got the next answer with "AmiProduct" or "ContainerProduct":

```
{
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 200,
    requestId: '91fc5fed-6cdc-42d6-97ec-1ed3cc9d5796',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  EntitySummaryList: []
}
```

I'm having difficulty understanding how to correctly implement this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The docs should be better. I spent a good 15 mins on the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/welcome.html and failed to find a full list of valid `EntityType` values.

Some EntityType values are documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/seller-products.html

- AmiProduct
- ContainerProduct

It looks like these types correspond to the product types in the index of the seller guide here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace/latest/userguide/machine-learning-products.html. It's not clear what the other valid values are.

Some other EntityType values are documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/private-marketplace.html

- Experience
- Procurement Policy

It looks the way to go for now is to scrounge these valid values from examples in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/welcome.html. Not the best developer experience :grimace:

Comment: Thanks a lot for your anwer. Talking about the implementation Is this the correct way to implement the aws sdk ?

Comment: It is. Try replacing `EntityType: 'Product'` in your code with `EntityType: 'AmiProduct'`. This should give you a proper response from AWS, rather than the `ValidationException` you were encountering earlier.

Comment: Thankyou. I tried it, now it gives to me a correct answer but with a $metadata and EntitySummaryList values and the array of EntitySummaryList is empty.

Comment: Yes, that means your seller does not have any products with `EntityType === AmiProduct'. Try the other EntityTypes, like `ContainerProduct`, etc.

Comment: Also: it just struck me that you might be looking at the wrong API entirely. AWS Marketplace seems to be for "products that run on AWS", as mentioned here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace

Comment: If you're looking to get a listing of *physical* products being sold by your seller partner, I believe you need to use this other API: https://developer.amazonservices.in/

Comment: You can only sell digital products on AWS Marketplace. For physical ones, worth looking at Amazon Seller Partner APIs: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api

Comment: So in this case is not possible to use the SDK? And Yes, what I'm trying to do is to get the products published in  amazon.com website.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are a seller, that you have registered successfully with your AWS account. You can then use Marketplace APIs.

To use them, you have to create an IAM role or a user with policies to grant access to invoke the selected APIs like `listEntities`, `describeEntity`, etc.

Here I again assume you have the Cognito authorized credentials if using AWS SDK.

Now to view the list of products **successfully published**, you use `listEntites` command.

> You can only view AMI or Containter product types. Read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/marketplace-catalog/latest/api-reference/seller-products.html).

It uses minimum two required parameters `Catalog` and `EntityType`. The former has a fixed value `AWSMarketplace`, and latter can have a value either `AmiProduct` or `ContainerProduct`.

To get a detailed information about a specific product, you use `describeEntity` command. It takes minimum 2 required parameters `Catalog` and `EntityID`.

The former again has a fixed value `AWSMarketplace`. For latter, you'll obtain it from the `listEntites` response.

Comment: I have refined my question to provide more details. I have already set up the IAM role. I have found a link that provides the information I need to retrieve and I am now attempting to retrieve it using the AWS SDK.

Comment: Now it's clear. You're talking regarding Amazon Seller APIs and not Amazon Web Services (AWS) ones. The former is an ecommerce platform and latter a cloud-computing provider. Therfore, you cannot use AWS SDKs to get data for Amazon ecommerce products. People often confuse the two to be the same platforms. For your case (outside the realm of AWS), you can check this useful FBA client to easily work with the Inventory APIs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sp-api-sdk/fba-inventory-api-v1

Comment: Oh, ok. Thankyou. In fact, I started checking the sp-api. But they say there something about use the SDK and don't need to create the signature and since that I started to find out in the SDK docs. Thanks a lot. I will check iout the package.